# Как выполнить скрипт только при первом просмотре страницы?

Tags: php, javascript, google-tag-manager

Добрый день!
Нужно поместить на страницу с заказом скрипт (js массив dataLayer с данными для GTM). Но, выполниться он должен при первом просмотре страници который происходит после подверждения заказа на странице корзины.
На страницу с заказом можно попасть по ссылке с ЛК, письма на почту и после оформления заказа.
Какой самый простой и нормальный вариант это сделать?

Comment: Можно первый раз записать `cookie` и проверять, если параметр есть, то не исполнять скрипт.

Comment: @erm Думал об этом, но если перейти с другого устройства все выполниться заново.

Comment: Тогда можно в БД записывать, что пользователь уже видел эту страницу и просто чекать БД.